# Replace multiple symbols using replace()

Tags: python, replace

How can I replace multiple symbols with the method `replace()`? Is it possible to do that with just one `replace()`? Or is there any better ways?

The symbols can look like this for example `-`,`+`,`/`,`'`,`.`,`&`.

Comment: I think regex would do this best

Comment: Depending on what you want, a list comprehension can give separate variants of the string, e.g. `s = 'GATCCAGATCCCCATAC'`, `[s.replace(k, "Q") for k in ("G", "T")]`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.sub) and put the characters in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
import re
re.sub('[-+/\'.&]', replace_with, input)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may do it using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with *generator* expression (without importing any library) as:

```
>>> symbols = '/-+*'
>>> replacewith = '.'
>>> my_text = '3 / 2 - 4 + 6 * 9'  # input string

#  replace char in string if symbol v
>>> ''.join(replacewith  if c in symbols else c for c in my_text)
'3 . 2 . 4 . 6 . 9'   # Output string with symbols replaced
```

Comment: Despite `re` being popular, I feel genexs like these are more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

```
# '7' -> 'A', '8' -> 'B'
print('asdf7gh8jk'.replace('7', 'A').replace('8', 'B'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only do one symbol replace, what you could do is create the old strings and new strings list and loop them:

```
string = 'abc'
old = ['a', 'b', 'c']
new = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for o, n in zip(old, new):
    string = string.replace(o, n)

print string
>>> 'ABC'
```